# How do return an ajax error when broken the request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on a Django website with many webservices(Rest/Piston) which returns json data.

This is the function that calls the webservice; it sometimes works fine, but in certain errors it doesn't return an error message, only "undefined error".
How can I view the error message or know what the error is?

```
function ws(p_url, p_json, p_type, p_auth, p_before, p_success, p_finally, p_async) {
    dict = {
       url : p_url,
       beforeSend : function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', p_auth);
          eval(p_before);
       },
       cache : false,
       type : p_type,
       data : p_json,
       async : false,
       contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       processData : false,
       dataType : 'json',
       timeout : 10000,
       success : function(json, textStatus) {
          eval(p_success);
       },

       error: function(e) {     
          alert("Error "+e.responseText);
          return false;
       },
       complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {
          alert("Complete");
       }
   };
   $.when(
       $.ajax(dict) ).done(function(){
          eval(p_finally);
          preLoader.fadeOut(300);
          return resposta;
       }).fail(function(fail_msg){
          alert("Fail: "+fail_msg);
       }
   );
};
```

Comment: Do your webservices return the json message "undefined error"? If so, then your problem is probably on the server end.

Comment: I would expect `alert("RES:>> "+e.Message);` to always be undefined. Shouldn't that be `e.responseText`? It would also be helpful to check the values of `arguments[1]` and `arguments[2]`

Comment: @KevinB
Yes, it is. I tried a lot of ways and I copy the source with error.
I have tried with responseText and arguments[x], but always returns undefined.

Comment: @JustinGingyMcDonald When I access the webservice directly(via GET or POST), or debugging via Firefox(the XHR Request), it returns the json, but it enter in the error function instead of get the value to the "Success" function.

Comment: @Jx_, If the server returns a successful http status code and you are able to view the response content trough a debugger, but the error handler is getting called, then it could be that the response is not valid JSON. Have you tried to validate the JSON response using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: @plalx, I see the Json in the Firebug Debugger and it is ok.
The problem is that Ajax returns "Undefined error" in the error handler. I dont know what can happens.

Comment: @Jx_, by `return` do you mean it alerts 'Undefined error'? In that case, it would technically mean that the server responded with the string 'Undefined error', but you are saying that the server effectively returns JSON. Can you post a printscreen of the response in FireBug and also replace your `alert` by `console.log(arguments);` and post the output produced in the console. I really suspect that your server is returning a string error message wich in that case, will make parsing the response as JSON fail and will invoke the error handler.